# Finding sixth term of binomial expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Finding sixth term of binomial expansion.
Given

$(y^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{\frac{1}{3}})^n$. Also given that Binomial coefficient for third term from last is $45$. Now Binomial coefficient for third term from last = binomial coefficient of $(n-3+2)th$ term from beginning. This gives me answer to be $n=45$, but it is $20$. May I know where I am wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I would say, binomial coefficient fof third term from last = ${n \choose n-2} = 45 \Rightarrow n = 10$ (if I correctly understand the query).

Comment: Binomial coefficients are symmetric, so the third term from the end is the same as third term from the beginning. Now, with $n=45$ the terms are: $1, 45, 990, 14190...$ Wait! See, it is the _second_, not the third term which is 45. Hence this is not what we need.

By trying a few more values, we arrive at $n=10$.